# How do I render only part of a texture to a point sprite in OpenGL ES for Android?

Tags: opengl-es, textures

Using the libgdx framework, I've figured out how to render a texture to a point sprite. The problem is, it renders the entire texture to the point sprite, where I only want a small part of it (since it's an isometric tile image).

Here's a snippet from some demo code I wrote...

```
create()
{
    renderer = new ImmediateModeRenderer();

    tiles = Gdx.graphics.newTexture(
        Gdx.files.internal("data/tiles2.png"),
        TextureFilter.MipMap,
        TextureFilter.Linear,
        TextureWrap.ClampToEdge,
        TextureWrap.ClampToEdge);

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.6f, 0.7f, 0.9f, 1);

    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL11.GL_POINT_SPRITE_OES);

    Gdx.gl11.glTexEnvi(
        GL11.GL_POINT_SPRITE_OES, 
        GL11.GL_COORD_REPLACE_OES,
        GL11.GL_TRUE);

    Gdx.gl10.glPointSize(s);

    tiles.bind();
}

render()
{
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    renderer.begin(GL10.GL_POINTS);

    // render 3 point sprites at various 3d points
    renderer.vertex(-.1f, 0, -.1f);
    renderer.vertex(0, 0, 0);
    renderer.vertex(.1f, 0, .1f);

    // ... more vertices here if needed (one for each sprite) ...

    renderer.end();
}
```

Comment: Update: As a work around, I had to split my texture images into separate files (loaded individually). This adds a bit of loading time, but it's ok with a few images (worried about when I have 100 textures though...). A caveat I didn't foresee is that OpenGL ES (<2.0)  requires that images be power of 2, and point sprites must be square!

Answer (score 4):

With OpenGL ES 1.x, i gess there is no solution. With OpenGL ES 2.x, you can use gl_PointCoord in fragment shader to select a part of your texture.

A typical PointSprite Fragment shader:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif 
uniform sampler2D tex0;

void main() 
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex0, gl_PointCoord);
}
```

So, you can modify it for 16 square textures in one texture:

```
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex0, gl_PointCoord*0.25+displacement);
```

One last word, if you are developing for mobile devices, keep you fragment very short and don't use branch.